# Shutdown still available on Ctrl+Alt+Del screen despite being disabled from group policy on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, group-policy, ctrl-alt-delete

We're experiencing an issue on Windows 10. When disabling the Shutdown option for users via Group Policy, the option disappears from the Start Menu, but doesn't disappear on the Ctrl+Alt+Del screen.

We're using the "User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Start Menu and Taskbar\Remove and prevent access to the Shut Down, Restart, Sleep, and Hibernate commands " policy setting, or alternatively we're setting the

"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\NoClose" registry key to 1

Using the exact same settings properly disabled the Ctrl+Alt+Del screen using the previous versions (we tested on Win7 and Windows 8.1).

According to this page, this setting should still disable shutdown and restart on the Ctrl+Alt+Del screen:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt484191%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Can someone offer some insight on this issue?

Is this something that changed in Windows 10, or is it a bug? If it's a change, how can we accomplish this on Win 10?

Comment: This behavior limited to just a single user or all users on the domain?  I tested it on my machine and the policy works.  You are using Version 1511 and the current build?

Comment: Hi! The setting is supposed to be set only for a single user.  I'm using version 10.0.10240 which is a bit old, will try a newer one if I get a chance.

Comment: The link you provided applies to the current build of Windows 10, while I don't believe that to be a possible explanation for the behavior, the current version should be used whenever possible.  So  are you modifying the domain policy or the local domain policy if its only a single user?

Comment: Here is a link from the [server fault wizards](http://serverfault.com/questions/27564/how-do-i-disable-the-shutdown-in-the-ctrlaltdelete-menu-for-authenticated-us). Hopefully the `Ctrl+Alt+Del` method works for you.

Comment: I've tested the behavior with build 10.0.10586. I'm editing the local group policy.

Comment: @DrZoo thanks for the link! Setting the machine wide Group policy from registry,
`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\Explorer]
"NoClose"=dword:00000001`

Comment: @torgabor did that do the trick?

Comment: When you run the rsop.msc command, what does it show? Does it show the command as disabled? Have you tried gpupdate /force?

Comment: @DrZoo Yup, it did. Somehow, when editing my post, I managed to chop off the end :( My bad.

Comment: @torgabor awesome! Put it as an answer and mark it as answered

Answer (score -1):

You can also set who is allowed to Shutdown the system from Computer "Configuration > Windows Settings > User Rights Assignments > Shut down the system".

To remove Task Manager go to "User Configuration > Administrative Templates > All Settings > Remove Task Manager"

Comment: Hi! Removing the current user Configuration > Windows Settings > User Rights Assignments > Shut down the system". doesn't disable the Shutdown from the Ctrl+Alt+Del page either. Also I don't want to disable the Task manager

Answer (score -1):

Try this **"User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Start Menu & Taskbar > Remove And Prevent Access To Shut Down Command"**

Comment: Hi! We've already tried that, as I mentioned in my post.